# <command-line>:0:11: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

Problem with compiling.

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
c89
cmake version 2.8.7
```

Not sure how to start with this one. I have googled it but couldn't come up with anything.

This is the warning I am getting:

```
<command-line>:0:11: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by default]
```

I am using cmake as the build system that creates the Makefile that I will compile. However, I am not sure why I am getting this warning. I have never had that before.

Can any one point me in the right direction. I am not sure what information I should provide to help solve this problem.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: What code are you compiling? What's at line 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect a warning like this if you had a line like the following in one of your source files:

```
#undef FOO BAR BAZ
```

The `BAR` and `BAZ` are ignored by the compiler, hence the warning.  What's at character 11 of your command-line?  Can you post the command line?

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused. What do you mean 'post the command line" Are you taking about the shell? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever the command line is that triggered the warning you reported.  There is likely a call to gcc before the warning -- that's what we need to see.  Add it to your question.

Comment: Problem solved. As part of my CMAKE_C_FLAGS I had this by mistake. -Unreachable-code. However, it should had been -Wunreachable-code. So the problem is solved now. Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense.  `-Unreachable-code` does the equivalent of `#undef nreachable-code`, which passes 3 tokens to `#undef`: `nreachable`, `-`, and `code`.  (It might be nice if gcc warned about that.)